# Why is my queue list not working as FIFO in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, doubly-linked-list, fifo

I am trying to implement queues with double linked list in java.
I have two methods `enqueue()` to add item and `dequeue()` to remove item.
I want it as First In First Out.
This is the code:

```
public void enqueue(T newEntry){ // T as generic type
    Node<T> newNode = new Node(newEntry,null,null); // Node(T element, Node prev,Node next)
    if(isEmpty()){
        firstNode = newNode;
        lastNode = newNode;
    }
    else{
        
        
        firstNode.prev = newNode;
        firstNode = newNode;
        
        numberOfElement++;
    }
}

public T dequeue(){ // remove node1
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw new NullPointerException("Queue is empty");
    }
    else{
        Node<T> node = firstNode; // get node1
        
        if(node != lastNode){ 
            
            firstNode.next.prev = null; // remove link from node2 to node1
            firstNode = node.next; // firstNode will now be node2
            node.next = null; // remove node1 link to node2
            
            numberOfElement--;
        }
        else{
            firstNode=null;lastNode=null; // first and last node reset to null
        }
        return node.element; // return element of removed node1
    }
}
```

Running these code in order:

```
enqueue("first"); // node1
enqueue("second"); // node2
enqueue("third"); // node3
enqueue("fourth"); // node4
System.out.println(dequeue());
System.out.println(dequeue());
```

will print:

```
fourth
third
```

instead of:

```
first
second
```

Comment: You're putting new nodes at the start, and also removing nodes from the start. A queue adds to the one end and pulls from the *other* end

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
firstNode = newNode;
```

ensures that the newly-added node is at the head of the queue, which you surely don't want.

You meant to assign to lastnode.